# Unbind a specific Jquery event by event pointer/reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need is something like:

```
var MyEventPointer = $('body').on('MyCustomEvent','.myClass',function(e){
   // do something
});

var MyEventPointer2 = $('body').on('MyCustomEvent','.myClass',function(e){
   // do something
});

$('body').unbindByEventID(MyEventPointer);
```

`MyEventPointer` is a pointer to a specific event handler. Even though the two event handlers are exactly identical, only one is unbound because they have different unique identifiers, returned on creation. This should work like the way I can store a reference to a timer in a variable and disable the timer again later using its reference. I know Jquery stores Unique IDs for events, but I don't know if I can get to them. Is this possible to do with Jquery or will I need to role my own solution? The event needs to be delegated so that both current and future instances of `.myClass` are included.

### Update:

**Sample Code:**

```
<tr><td><input class="MyWidget" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="MyWidget" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="MyWidget" /></td></tr>
<!-- Repeats n times, rows are added and deleted dynamically -->
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Creation
$('.MyWidget').MyWidget();


// The plugin
$.fn.MyWidget = function (options) {
   return this.each(function () {
      new ATK.MyWidget(this, options);
   });
};

// The widget class
ATK.MyWidget = function (element, options) {
   // constructor
}
ATK.MyWidget.prototype = new ATK.ParentWidget();

ATK.MyWidget.prototype.SetFilterEvent = function(Selector) {
   var base = this;   
   $('body').on('MyCustomEvent',Selector,function(e){base.eMyCustomEvent(e,this)});
}

ATK.MyWidget.prototype.eMyCustomEvent = function(e,eventThis) {
   console.log(this.protected.$element.attr('id')+' has detected that '+$(eventThis).attr('id')+' has changed.');
}
```

Comment: What you would get as a return value in both cases is the jQuery object for the `<body>`, not a unique reference

Comment: True, my example above is pseudo code- I'm trying to figure out how I can get a unique ID back instead of the Jquery object.

Comment: That won't work in this case, since the class(object) listening for changes should not modify the elements it's listening to.

Comment: Deleted my comments as Jasper's answer makes more sense ;)

Comment: `MyEventPointer` is a JavaScript object, not an event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
function MyEventPointer1(e){
   // do something
});

function MyEventPointer2(e){
   // do something
});

$('body').on('MyCustomEvent','.myClass', MyEventPointer1);
$('body').on('MyCustomEvent','.myClass', MyEventPointer2);

$('body').off('MyCustomEvent','.myClass', MyEventPointer1);
```

---

More specifically in your case with classes, you can easily apply the above pattern and it works:

```
ATK.MyWidget.prototype.SetFilterEvent = function(Selector) {
    this.event = function(e) {this.eMyCustomEvent(e, this);}
    $('body').on('MyCustomEvent',Selector,this.event);
}

ATK.MyWidget.prototype.RemoveFilterEvent = function(Selector) {
    $('body').off('MyCustomEvent',Selector,this.event);
}
```

(You might want to check to make sure that this.event isn't null and set it to null in the constructor, or maybe it's more efficient to declare this.event in the constructor to be this function, or something like that, but this basically does the job.)

Comment: That uses two functions. In my case, there can be only one function. The function is a method of a class, and the class has n instances in the document at any given time. The instance know when they are created and when they are about to be destroyed, but are not aware of other instances (by design). In order for delegation to work, the class has to attach the event to a wrapper that is known to exist outside of itself, in this case the body. All the instances are listening for the same thing, but when the event occurs, each instance needs notified so it can process the change by itself.

Comment: Seriously, downvoting because there are additional restrictions not mentioned in your original question that I couldn't have known?

Comment: @Nick: Whether or not that's even a problem depends on what technique you are using to emulate classes in javascript. And even when that's a problem, you can easily circumvent it by using "anonymous" functions which are stored as a class property (practically what you are doing in other strategies...). If you want me to be more concrete, you need to show me more code.

Comment: I was trying to keep the question as simple as possible- just a way to get a UID from event handler creation. But I can certainly post more code above if it would be useful.

Comment: @Nick My code works for your sample, so yes, you'd need to post a new sample for which the code I provide does not work before I can modify my code to work in that case as well. The description you gave is reasonable, but it uses terms like "class" which doesn't actually have a meaning in javascript, and though that's usually not a problem, it is here.

Comment: I've added some sample code, hopefully that helps to clarify?

Comment: I added code that solves the problem that comes up in your case.

Comment: Having this page still open after having done some other things, I would like to add that I greatly appreciate it when people (and in this case Nick) provide "minimal samples" (or as he put it "keep the question as simple as possible"). It was just so that here we ran into troubles that were hard to resolve with only the first minimal sample which led to me needing another minimal sample (but less minimal, since it needed not to be solved by my first solution)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different identical events on an element I mean if you want to register more than one event handler on the same element then you can use `event namespace`, i.e.

```
$('body').on('MyCustomEvent.nameSpaceOne','.myClass',function(e){
    // do something
});

$('body').on('MyCustomEvent.nameSpaceTwo','.myClass',function(e){
    // do something
});
```

Remove the first handler using the `event namespace` and in this case it;s `nameSpaceOne`

```
$('body').off('MyCustomEvent.nameSpaceOne', '.myClass');
```

[**An example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GhYf5/1/).

Comment: Will both handlers pickup `MyCustomEvent` (without a namespace) when it's triggered? ie. `.trigger('MyCustomEvent')`

Comment: @Nick, Yes if without a namespace then but I think why you should use it without a `namespace`.